# Как избегать круглых float чисел в питоне,допустим 3.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, типы-данных, преобразование

[image: Пример моего кода]

Это код который я написал ради прикола,и мне бы хотелось,что бы такие некрасивые числа округлялись,и выводилось не 3.0, а 3,как должно быть.

Comment: Добро пожаловать и одна ремарка, могли бы вы код оформить в виде блока текстового кода. Это поможет участникам возпроизвести ваш пример и оперативнее ответить на ваш вопрос

Comment: Оформите код как код, а не в виду картинки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Используйте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440708/8324991) спецификацию формата `g` (general) при выводе, тогда лишних нулей не будет:

```
a = 15/5
print(f'Среднее число: {a:g}')
a = 15/6
print(f'Среднее число: {a:g}')
```

Вывод:

```
Среднее число: 3
Среднее число: 2.5
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,всё работает как надо.